# Regex named group in different locations

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex pattern to catch pattern in different optional locations.

Let me explain in an example:

Test strings:

```
x-test
y-test
z-test
test-t
```

I need to capture x,y,z,t in same named group

Please check it from here:

https://regex101.com/r/Zui48R/1

Comment: `(?:x|y|z)(?=-test)|(?<=test-)t` - https://regex101.com/r/TK8HGO/1? `(?|(x|y|z)-test|test-(t))` - https://regex101.com/r/TK8HGO/2? Or do you want to get the result into a named capturing group? `(?J)(?:(?<group_name>x|y|z)-test|test-(?<group_name>t))` - https://regex101.com/r/TK8HGO/3?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You would need to get `group_name`, if it's null, get `group_name2` instead